# Problema al comparar datos de una matriz a otra java

Tags: java, matrices, matriz

espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esto:
tengo dos matrices de la siguiente forma;

```
    String[][] datos = null;
    String[][] comparar = null;
```

las cuales lleno con metodos externos;

```
  datos = metodo1();
  comparar = metodo2();
```

y necesito comprar si un dato de la matriz 1 comparar existe en la matriz datos, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        if (datos[i][1].equals(comparar[1][4])) {
            System.out.println("Aqui esta!:\n" + datos[i][0] + " " + datos[i][1]);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aqui no esta!");
        }

    }
```

el problema esta en que aunque el dato que quiero buscar exite en la matriz datos siempre me imprime que no esta;

lo extraño es que si en ves de hacer esto en el if:

```
 datos[i][1].equals(comparar[1][4])
```

hago esto, mandarle la cadena de texto directamente:

```
 datos[i][1].equals("PRUEBA")
```

si lo encuentra !!!

he intentando hacer esto para evitar algun error con la matriz y el metodo equals:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {         
        String x=comparar[1][4];
        if (datos[i][1].equals(x)) {
            System.out.println("Aqui esta!:\n" + datos[i][0] + " " + datos[i][1]);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aqui no esta!");
        }

    }
```

y sigue fallando :(

solo funciona cuando le mando la cadena de texto completa.

gracias a los comentarios he hecho varios ejercicios como este, asumiendo que el valor que quiero buscar es este:"GPON001416C2";

```
     String x = comparar[1][4];
    if (comparar[1][4].equals("GPON001416C2")) {
        System.out.println("mismo valor");
        System.out.println(comparar[1][4] + " || GPON001416C2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("el valor es diferente");
        System.out.println(comparar[1][4] + " || GPON001416C2");
    }
```

la consola me arroja esto:

```
el valor es diferente
GPON001416C2 || GPON001416C2
```

sigue  fallando a pesar que el valor es claramente el mismo!, intente utilizar el método replaceAll() para descartar que espacios en la cadena de texto pero el resultado es el mismo:

```
 String x = comparar[1][4].replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: Ya viste que valor devuelve el elemento `1, 4`? Si es diferente al valor que ingresas directamente, tiene sentido que no lo encuentre

Comment: @Mateo claro amigo es el mismo valor por eso se me hace extraño

Comment: Y qué pasa si imprimes, `
 comparar[1][4].equals("PRUEBA")` te sigue danto true?

Comment: @jacobo he editado la pregunta con tu recomendacion, sigue fallando

Answer (score 1):

Al realizar esto, solo estas iterando lo que vendrían a ser todas las filas con la primera columna `datos[i][1]`.trata de declarar las variables con dato fijo fuera del for (x)

```
  for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
String x=comparar[1][4];
                if (datos[i][1].equals(comparar[1][4])) {
                    System.out.println("Aqui esta!:\n" + datos[i][0] + " " + datos[i][1]);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Aqui no esta!");
                }
        
            }
```

puede que el dato que busques no siempre se encuentre en la primera columna por lo cual debes iterar tanto las filas `matriz[i]` como las columnas `matriz[i][j]`

```
datos[i][1].equals("PRUEBA")
```

Te imprimirá varias veces no encontrado por que puede que el valor buscado no se encuentre en la primera fila primera columna por lo cual no caerá en la condicional `if` si no en la condicional `else` el cual imprime el mensaje `"Aqui no esta!"`

```
if (datos[i][1].equals(comparar[1][4])) {
                    System.out.println("Aqui esta!:\n" + datos[i][0] + " " + datos[i][1]);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Aqui no esta!");
```

Ejemplo corregido:

```
//"Prueba" se encuentra en datos[3][1]
    String[][]datos={{"a","b"},
                     {"c","d"},
                     {"e","f"},
                     {"´g","Prueba"}};
    
    
    String[][]comparar={{"g","h"},{"a","b","c","d","Prueba"}};
//"Prueba" se encuentra en comparar[1][4];
```

//declaramos las variables x y un booleano el cual ayudara a imprimir el mensaje de no encontrado

```
  String x=comparar[1][4];
  boolean encontrado=false;
```

recorremos tanto filas como columnas, por que como te mencione antes puede que el dato no se encuentre exclusivamente en la primera columna de tu matriz

```
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) { 
         for (int j=0;j<datos[i].length; j++) {     
            if (datos[i][j].equals(x)) {
          //mostramos las coordenandas en la matriz datos  donde esta el valor buscado
                System.out.println("Aquí esta en las coordenadas: [" +i+"]["+j+"]"); 
          //cambiamos el valor del booleano si se encontró el valor buscado          
                encontrado=true;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
//en caso no se hay encontrado luego de todas las iteraciones imprimiremos el
//mensaje de no encontrado usando el booleano, que no cambio a `true` por que no se
//encontró el  valor buscado

     if(!encontrado){
                System.out.println("No se encontro");
            }
```

Comment: gracias amigo, intente como indicaste pero sigue fallando, con el mismo principio cuando le mando la cadena de texto con el valor que quiero encontrar si lo encuentra pero cuando le mando la posición de la matriz no lo encuentra;
te comparto lo que imprime en consola, asumiendo que el valor que quiero buscar es el siguiente "GPON001416C2";
   String x = comparar[1][4];
   if (datos[i][j].equals(x))
consola;
No se encontro.

pero si le mando la cadena de texto que quiero buscar;
if (datos[i][j].equals("GPON001416C2"))
Consola;
Aquí esta en las coordenadas: comparar[1][4]

Comment: podes editar la pregunta agregando los valores de ambas matrices,para poder ayudarte

Comment: amigo el problema es que la matriz datos tiene 4000 filas y 2 columnas y la matriz comparar tiene 32 filas y 4 columnas, no se como agregarlas a la pregunta, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: esta raro que digas que comparar tiene 32 fila 4 columnas y luego obtengas x apartir de comparar[1][4] cuando la columnacon indice  4 no existe los indice son a apartir de 0 revisa este [ejemplo](https://www.codiva.io/p/bce27466-1d07-470e-a0f0-ad0c25cbc3e8)

Comment: amigos he encontrado la razon del problema y espero esto le pueda servir alguien mas en el futuro, el problema esta al llenar la matriz comparar, cuando guardo el valor como ejemplo: 
comparar [0][1] ="GPON001416C2"  el lo guarda asi: [63CGPON001416C2 asumo que esos valores adicionales los pone como identificador de ram no lo se exactamente.
el tema es que cuando intento hacer el .equals nunca me va a dar true porque cuando llamo a comparar[0][1].equals("GPON001416C2") osea [63CGPON001416C2 !=GPON001416C2
no se si me explique bien, no se como solucionar esto